# How to use the IF function 1 time?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

hello I want to use the if function 1 time and I don't want it to repeat. How can I do?

Score Code:

```
public void IncrementScore()
{
    // Add to the score
    score++;

    // Update the score text
    scoreText.text = "" + score;

    // Is there a new hiscore?
    if (score > hiscore)
    {

        // Set the new hiscore
        hiscore = score;

        // Save the new hiscore
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("hiscore", hiscore);

        // Update the hiscore text
        hiscoreText.text = "" + hiscore;
    }

    Congratulations.instance.Score25Congratulations();
}
```

If function I want to use 1 time

```
public void Score25Congratulations()
{
    if (CollectorScript.instance.hiscore == 25)
    {
        Congratulations25.SetActive(true); //I want it to show 1 time
        Time.timeScale = 0f;
    }
}
public void Score25CongratulationsButton()
{
    Congratulations25.SetActive(false);
    Time.timeScale = 1f;
}
```

I want it to show 1 time, but it doesn't happen repeatedly. So if the number is equal to 25 Congratulations25.SetActive (true); It repeats, I don't want it to repeat, I just want it to come out once, is such a thing possible?

Comment: Note that UnityScript is a programming language derived from Javascript, and it was created for Unity. Unity deprecated it in 2017 in favour of the C# programming language. With it being a completely separate programming language, using the `[unityscript]` tag on your C# question is confusing, so I've removed it for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general I would only check it for a new Highscore which already reduces the work.

And then add a simple flag which controlls that the message is only displayed the first time 25 is reached.

In general I would also not go through Singleton patterns forth and back but rather call it like

```
bool congrats25alreadyDisplayed;

private void Awake ()
{
    congrats25alreadyDisplayed = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("congrats25", 0) > 0;
}

public void IncrementScore()
{
    // Add to the score
    score++;

    // Update the score text
    scoreText.text = score.ToString();

    // Is there a new hiscore?
    if (score > hiscore)
    {
        // Set the new hiscore
        hiscore = score;

        // Save the new hiscore
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("hiscore", hiscore);

        // Update the hiscore text
        hiscoreText.text = hiscore.ToString();

        if(hiscore >= 25 && !congrats25alreadyDisplayed)
        {
            // Set flag so never displayed again
            congrats25alreadyDisplayed = true;
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("congrats25", 1);
            PlayerPrefs.Save();

            Congratulations.instance.Score25Congratulations();
        }
    }
}
```

And in your other script simply

```
public void Score25Congratulations()
{ 
    Congratulations25.SetActive(true);
    Time.timeScale = 0f;
}
```

---

Just a sidenote: It is `Highscore` ;)